# APA Citation Single Source

Tags: citations, apa

If you read an article then write a paragraph based on what you learned, do you cite the article at the end of the paragraph? Or do you have to cite after each time you mention something that isn't common knowledge? I've only been able to find help on citing quotes and single sentences. What if I have more 2-3 sentences back to back that are not quoted but from the same source? I would imagine its just at the end since it would look weird having the same citation after each sentence wouldn't it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just once at the end of the last sentence. The only reason you would need to cite the same source twice is if you refer to it in different places in the text. If all the information from one source is sequential, you only need to cite once.

Comment: This is wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

*The answer by Lea is wrong in APA!*

There are two kinds of citations: direct quotes and paraphrases.

1. **Direct quotes** of less than 40 words are enclosed in quotations marks. Direct quotes of 40 words or more are set off from the surrounding text as "block quotes". Direct quotes can be several sentences, even several paragraphs long, and the source for them is given once, usually at the end.
2. **Paraphrases** are handled differently. In APA the reference to a paraphrase must be given *inside* the paraphrasing sentence, that is: before the closing full stop. The reference, therefore, can only apply to the sentence (or clause) that it is part of.

   Example (note the position of the full stop):

   > <s>Bla bla bla. (Source, 2014)</s> <= This is wrong!
   >   Bla bla bla (Source, 2014). <= This is right.

   **If your paraphrase spans several sentences, each sentence must contain a reference to the source!** The APA Manual (2009, pp. 175f.) gives two examples:

   > Among epidemiological samples, Kessler (2003) found that early onset social anxiety disorder results in a more potent and severe course. Kessler also found.... The study also showed that there was a high rate of comorbidity with alcohol abuse or dependence and major depression (Kessler, 2003).

   And:

   > Early onset results in a more persistent and severe course (Kessler, 2003). Kessler (2003) also found....